# Python - Access to /tmp/[random_string] denied (2) when writing to temporary file.

Tags: python, temporary-files, access-denied

So first off, I am running a python 3.5 script in a virtual environment on an Ubuntu computer.

My code is as follows:

```
handle = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()
handle.write(b'Some stuff here')
handle.flush()
```

This should work properly. In fact, if I go into the interactive console and import tempfile, and then enter this exact code it works perfectly fine. However, when I run my script I get an error that looks like the following:

```
Access to /tmp/[name of temp file] denied. (2)
```

I have also tried to add a directory and create the temporary file in the local directory of the script that is creating it and I still receive this error.

Any help or advice you can give would be much appreciated.

Comment: user running `python` command & the script are same ?

Comment: Yes, both under my user. Even running the python interactive console in the same virtual environment. That's why it makes no sense to me at all.